# How to add if function in django html template

Tags: html, css, django

I want to add an `if` function in an html template of my django project.

If the variables datas is null, it will show the text "The results is null", if the variables datas is not empty, it will show the table for the data in datas.

Here's what I write, but it raises the error

```
Invalid block tag on line 13: 'if(isEmpty($('#datas')))', expected 'endblock'. 
Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

How could I deal with it?

```
  {% if(isEmpty($('#datas'))) %}
      <h3>The results is null.</h3>
    {% else %}
    <table style="table-layout:fixed;">
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>
    {% for i in datas %}
    <td>{{ i.1 }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [empty](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty) tag. Use it like this:

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed;">
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>
{% for i in datas %}
    <td>{{ i.1 }}</td>
    </tr>
  {% empty %}
    <h3>The results is null.</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

But, if you want to check if `datas` is empty beforehand, then I think its best to do it in views. You can try like this:

```
def some_view(request):
    context = {}
    datas = Data.objects.all()
    if datas.exists():
       context['data_exists'] = True
       context['datas'] = datas
    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

and use it template:

```
{% if not data_exists %}
      <h3>The results is null.</h3>
{% else %}
....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use if condition

if you are sending datas from a view

**view**

```
def index(request):
    datas = None
    context = {"datas":datas}
    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

**template**

```
{% if datas %}
    <!-- your table -->
{% else %}
    <h3>The results is null</h3>
{% endif %}
```